# Literature suggestions: Stochastic Integration; for intuition; for non-mathematicians.

Tags: reference-request, big-list, advice

I would like to get a good feeling of stochastic integration in a more intuitive way (to be able to easily explain it to a first year math student or a physicist). Example of what I want to understand better:

1. Which processes we can put as integrators, integrands when we calculate stochastic integrals, what are the limitations, etc?
2. What was the history of development of stochastic integration? ( I know that key people are Meyer, Itō, but maybe somebody occasionally found nice article about the path of development of the discipline).

**I have seen several posts**, one of it is full of references to nice books, here is a link:
[What are some easier books for studying martingale?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341723/what-are-some-easier-books-for-studying-martingale)

**My recommendation of books to read:** I really liked the prefrace given by *P. Medvegyev, Stochastic Integration Theory* ( did not see anyone mentioning this book here) and of course the way the material is treated at famous *Rogers, Williams, Diffusions Markov Processes and Martingales* has some storytelling magic. It is not as dry as other books can be. I like the dependence charts people put in the books, like *R.Schilling* did in *Measures, Integrals and Martingales*.

To sum up, do you know any good overview, or guide or a book that deals with theory providing a concise story, that glues the material together.
Sorry if I ask something inappropriate or I am repeating many posts here.

Comment: A first year undergraduate?

Comment: me? almost surely )

Answer (score 1):

**Update on subquestion 2:** a friend advised to read history of the discipline in this paper: [A short history of stochastic integration and mathematical finance: the early years, 1880–1970](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnms/1196285381)

Answer (score 0):

I find *Martingales and stochastic integration* by *P.E. Kopp* a nice introduction as well.